# Some characters replaced with % sign python

Tags: python, python-3.x, url, character-encoding, python-requests

So pretty much what I'm making is a short script that takes a url, unshortens it, and prints out part of it for you to see. The problem I've run into is when I tried this url: [https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vnc®-viewer-for-google-ch/iabmpiboiopbgfabjmgeedhcmjenhbla](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vnc%C2%AE-viewer-for-google-ch/iabmpiboiopbgfabjmgeedhcmjenhbla). What happens is when python tries to print the "vnc®-viewer-for-google-ch" part, it comes out as "vnc%C2%AE viewer for google ch" instead. Is there a way to get it to print it properly? Hopefully that made sense.

My full code for it is here: https://repl.it/@Polloz/Extension-finder, I added some annotations to make it easier to understand

Comment: Please include your code in the body of your question, not just as an external link.

Comment: Also, the `%` stuff is part of the right URL. It's [URL encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).